# github SwiftSocket doesn't execute on iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I successfully followed all the steps in the github > SwiftSocket > Installation section.

It builds, but when I select my iPhone, and click Xcode play button, Xcode says "Build Succeeded" but nothing happens, and no icon appears on iPhone.

I tried on iPad, same result.

In the Issues page, I found this ominous oracle from 2019:...
"Looks like this project may have been ended due to Network.framework?"

Comment: Although the repo includes a sample app, it doesn't include a project to build that app. The project in the repo just builds the framework.  You will need to create your own sample app, perhaps using the included code to get started. Is there a particular reason you want to use this framework?  It hasn't been updated for a long time and as you found, the in-built Network framework on iOS does the same thing and much more.

Comment: My reason was just to get a simple socket going between iOS and windows 10 ASAP.  Maybe POSIX is the way to go.  Or, will Apple's Network Framework sockets communicate with Windows 10 POSIX socket?

Comment: POSIX is just an API. As is the Network Framework. As long as you use the same type of network socket (UDP or TCP) the api doesn't matter. Apple's Network framework is the recommended network socket api for iOS.